# How can I fix this? Graphc Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I would like to make a `graphcy` using `AJAX` and `MySQL`, I have the graphical but I can not use `MySQL` data in it.

jog is a column name that contains a `int` value.

My script:

```
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
            data: [
              <?php 
              $ver = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `servers`");

              while($dado = mysql_fetch_array ($ver))
                 {
                  echo "0.".$dado['jog'].", ";
              }


              ?>

            ]
        }]


    </script>
```

The original script is:

```
                    series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
            data: [
                0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451,    0.8418, 0.8264,    0.8258, 0.8232,    0.8233, 0.8258,
                0.8283, 0.8278, 0.8256, 0.8292,    0.8239, 0.8239,    0.8245, 0.8265,    0.8261, 0.8269,
                0.8273, 0.8244, 0.8244, 0.8172,    0.8139, 0.8146,    0.8164, 0.82,    0.8269, 0.8269,
                0.8269, 0.8258, 0.8247, 0.8286,    0.8289, 0.8316,    0.832, 0.8333,    0.8352, 0.8357,
                0.8355, 0.8354, 0.8403, 0.8403,    0.8406, 0.8403,    0.8396, 0.8418,     0.7006,
                0.7035, 0.7045, 0.6956, 0.6988, 0.6915, 0.6914, 0.6859, 0.6778, 0.6815, 0.6815,
                0.6843, 0.6846, 0.6846, 0.6923, 0.6997, 0.7098, 0.7188, 0.7232, 0.7262, 0.7266,
                0.7359, 0.7368, 0.7337, 0.7317, 0.7387, 0.7467, 0.7461, 0.7366, 0.7319, 0.7361,
                0.7437, 0.7432, 0.7461, 0.7461, 0.7454, 0.7549, 0.7742, 0.7801, 0.7903, 0.7879,
                0.7855, 0.7866, 0.7865, 0.7795, 0.7758, 0.7717, 0.761, 0.7497, 0.7471, 0.7473,
                0.7407, 0.7288, 0.7074, 0.6927, 0.7083, 0.7191, 0.719, 0.7153, 0.7156, 0.7158,
                0.714, 0.7119, 0.7129, 0.7129, 0.7049, 0.7095
            ]
        }]

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the outputted code? Use `view source` for this.

Comment: Sorry, Im new in this website and My country does not speak english, mine is not very good. My problem does not need the output code, I just want to insert the mysql collum 'jog' in this numbers.

Comment: Yes, but you say the javascript isn't working - what is the compiled javascript code that is outputted? You showed us an example with your own values, but what does the PHP echo? (Not the PHP code - the compiled code). Eg `<?php echo '<strong>test</strong>'; ?>` would have `<strong>test</strong>` as the compiled code.

Comment: I just want to echo the mysql values in    data : [], So I just have done a while for doing that, but this while does not work.. Soo The javascript is not working because of that.It is showing a graphical (outputted).In the PHP echo , its is echo some mysql values like these numbers in the example.

Comment: But what javascript does the PHP output?

Comment: javascript just make a graphycal.Like what I said, my problem is on getting those values.